# Array of structures for PowerPC Compiler

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization, powerpc

I have a problem, I was asked to declare an array of structures, with one structure inside like so:

```
typedef struct {
int a;
int b;
int c;
}blah;

int main()
{
    blah arr[1] = {{0, 0, 0}};
//...
}
```

Is the above initialization correct?

Comment: Yes. More characters so this will post.

Comment: Did you try it in a compiler?

Comment: @dbaupp, Yes, the compiler is telling me there are too many initializers. The compiler is for PowerPC...

Comment: GCC 4.4 through 4.7 don't complain at all.

Comment: Could you please specify the compiler version and the target platform?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's totally correct.

Array of length 1 is not much different from those containing multiple elements: they all are aggregate types and their initialization should be enclosed in curly braces. If your array had 2 elements, the initialization would be like

```
blah arr[2] = { {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0} };
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You don't need to specify the size if you're going to have an explicit initializer, let the compiler figure it out:

```
blah arr[] = { { 0, 0, 0 } };
```

I've also included spaces to make the nesting a bit clearer.

Comment: my way of specifying the number of structs in the array should not be a problem thought, correct?

Comment: do think it could be a compiler issue, this code is being compiled for PowerPC...